# Data structure for implementing an Address Book in Java

Tags: data-structures, addressbook, concurrent-collections

Which data structure from the Concurrent collections package will be suitable for implementing an address book?

Comment: what language? If java then ConcurrentSkipListMap.

Comment: java_geek sounds like java.

Comment: What does your data look like? Which operations do you want to support (and how efficiently)? Which one do you think is the most suitable (and why)?

Comment: I would infact use a Trie. Is there some data structure similar to trie in the concurrent package?

Comment: @Dukeling : Basically want to add/delete/edit/search entries in my address book

Comment: depends on how you'll use it. if only by name, HashMap-away! if also wanna sort/search, do a TreeSet-- s tree structure backed by HashMap